# doctrine php createQuery IN arrayAssociation

Tags: php, doctrine

I have entity Prop_alquiler with association

```
 /**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Prop_feature")
 * @JoinTable(name="baires_props_alquiler_features",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="prop_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="feature_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $features;
```

Now the idea is filter specifics Prop_feature id in createQuery sentence, the obvious problem with

```
JOIN p.features f WHERE f.id IN(1,2,...)
```

is that a Prop_alquiler has several Prop_features so the same Object Prop_alquiler will be repeated.

There is a simple way to make a ???

```
WHERE p.features IN(key values)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was silly, its very simple, in case of filters use

```
GROUP BY p.id
```

Thats it, hope this help anyone with the same wrong concept